# Discord.js V12 Muting everyone tagged, creating a role that locks all channels as well

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So this command, when an admin types `$mute @user1 @user2 @user3` it mutes everyone tagged, also if its the first time using the command on that server, it creates a new role "ModrajMute", but the problem I am having is when it creates that role, it doesn't lock all the channels for that role (error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined".
If anyone knows how to fix that for me, thank you

My code:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "mute")) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.channel.send('You do not have that permission! :x:').then(message.react(':x:'))
        let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "ModrajMute")
        const channels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type !== "category")
        if(!muteRole) {
      const MuteRole = await message.guild.roles.create({
    data:{
    name: `ModrajMute`,
    color: "DEFAULT",
    permissions: ['READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']

}}).then(message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(ch => {
    if (ch.type == "text")
        ch.overwritePermissions([
            {
                id: muteRole.id,
                deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
            },
        ], 'Needed to change permissions');
}) )
message.channel.send("Succesfully created the `ModrajMute` role, please write the command again and mute the person.")
} else if(!message.mentions.members.first()) return message.channel.send("Please mention a user or users that you want to mute.")
   if(message.mentions.members.first()) {
        message.mentions.members.forEach(member => member.roles.add(muteRole))
        message.channel.send("Succesfully muted the user/users.")
   }
    }})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const MuteRole` should be `const muteRole`. You are getting `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` because `muteRole` is undefined.

Comment: Hey, im kinda late, i've fixed it but now I get a "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'muteRole' before initialization" error.

Comment: Sorry I'm late as well. That means you're trying to access `muteRole` before you create it.